# Send custom data with ACRA without sending an exception itself

Tags: android, webview, exception, acra

Is it possible to send custom data with acra without actually having a Throwable?

I´ve seen that it is possible to append custom crashdata by using

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData()
```

But the data will only be send if there will follow an exception.

The intention of doing it is an app I´m working on, which uses webview and I want to send Javascript errors as well as native ones.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible at least if you look into the implementation details, but what about simply manufacturing an Exception to throw?  Exception handling is less efficient than other program flows, but that is probably not significant if you are going to be pushing the result to an external server anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the way, you just need to give null as parameter instead of an Exception, for example:

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue");
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);
```

These 2 lines will report this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Report requested by developer
```

With the following as custom data in the report:

```
{myKey:myValue}
```